# How to str_split string from right to left?

Tags: php

Let's say i have a number `10000` and i want to split it by 2 characters from right to left resulting in array something like this `[0] => 1,[1] => 00,[2] => 00`.
Is it somehow possible with `str_split($var, 2);` ?

Comment: Some clarification qs: Is it always an INT? Is it ever going to have commas in it? Are the array elements going to be an INT as well? (no doubles, no decimals, no commas, etc)

Comment: it will always be a INT, no decimlas or commas

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `preg_split` to check positions where the number of digits until the end is even.

```
$result = preg_split('~\B(?=(..)+$)~', '10000');
```

`\B` the non-word boundary, prevents to match the start of the string. *(The non-word boundary only matches between two digits)*
`(?=(..)+$)` is a lookahead that checks if the position is followed by an even number of characters.

---

Otherwise you can add a leading 0 when the string length is odd and remove it in the first item:

```
$str = '10000';

if ( strlen($str) & 1 ) {
    $res = str_split("0$str", 2);
    $res[0] = (int)$res[0];
} else {
    $res = str_split($str, 2);
}

print_r($res);
```

or shorter using the ternary operator:

```
$result = str_split( strlen($str) & 1 ? "0$str" : $str, 2);
$result[0] = (int)$result[0];
```

Comment: Its crazy what you can do with regex ... with what looks like a keyboard mash of chars :)

Answer (score 5):

There must be easier ways, but you can use something like:

```
array_map("strrev", array_reverse(str_split(strrev(10000), 2)));
```

---

```
[0] => 1
[1] => 00
[2] => 00
```

---

1. [strrev()](https://php.net/manual/en/function.strrev.php) - Reverse a string
2. [str_split()](https://php.net/manual/en/function.str-split.php) - Convert a string to an array
3. [array_reverse()](https://php.net/manual/en/function.array-reverse.php) - Return an array with elements in reverse
   order
4. [array_map()](https://php.net/manual/en/function.array-map.php) - Applies the callback to the elements of the given
   arrays

Comment: Nice sneaky use of array_map with strrev again. Brilliant :)

Comment: @IncredibleHat t The idea came after your comment, appreciated!

Comment: Well mine was a total mess, this is much much nicer, and cleaner!

Answer (score 0):

Ok nevermind I could do something like `strrev($string)` and then split it by 2

Comment: Wouldn't that put the elements in each array item backwards themselves? So you would have to go over the entire array and reverse the reverse, and then reverse the whole array itself? :) Seems counter-intuitive. 14387 = 78, 34, 1

Comment: yea you are right, then i don't know how i would do it